# Listview automatically get scroll up after every 2 seconds

Tags: android, listview

A thread using on an Oncreate method to get chat history from server to set on listview, the code is given below:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // new Comments(false).execute();
            new GetChatFromServer().execute();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1600);
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(run);
```

It's calling to GetChatFromServer class to get all recent updated chat history working fine but the problem is that when i scroll down listview it automatically scrolled up.

```
class GetChatFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        String chathistory;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            System.out.println("My url is>>>>" + chatHistoryUrl);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params)
                throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(chatHistoryUrl,
                    ServiceHandler.GET);
            chathistory = "{\"chatHistories\":" + jsonStr + "}";
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ChatHistory>>() {
            }.getType();
            chatHistories = (ArrayList<ChatHistory>) gson.fromJson(jsonStr,
                    listType);
            // ChatModel res = gson.fromJson(chathistory, ChatModel.class);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mAdapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatMainActivity.this,
                    chatHistories, sourceId);
            chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

    }
```

Please if anyone can help out to my problem. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mAdapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatMainActivity.this,
            chatHistories, sourceId);
    chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Your calling `setAdapter` again and again whenever you fetch data from server, what you need to do is set Adapter in `OnCreate` and call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` whenever you fetch data.

Here is the example:

```
String chathistory;
ChatMessageAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ........
    mAdapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatMainActivity.this, chatHistories, sourceId);
    chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

and in `onPostExecute`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I had implemented but its not working.anyway thank for support.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are recreating adapter every time. Initialize adapter once and replace data only in your onPostExecute

```
List chatHistories;



  // in onPostExecute
adapter.updateData(new_chatHistory);




// in your adapter
updateData(List new_chatHistory){

    chatHistories.addAll(new_chatHistory);

    and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```